# Is <element name="$etc[]"> invalid syntax?

Tags: html

For example, I've come across websites that use form elements such as inputs, where the name values use $s and square brackets (which is generally for things like arrays via GET/POST).

However, under [HTML4 6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2), it clearly states:

> ID and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Can I get some more information on this particular? I'd like to know if this is a violation -- and if it isn't, what rules govern this attribute? If it is a violation, how did we get here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A name attribute may usually begin with a `$`.

Unintuitive though it may seem, an `id` attribute value is a **NAME** token, while most `name` attribute values are **CDATA** (the `name` attribute on a `meta` element takes a **NAME** token though). See the **type** column in the [list of attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) in the specification for a quick reference (or the DTD for the definitive answer).

Comment: Thank you, this was a total blunder moment for me, hah. Names of tokens types aren't element names themselves.

Comment: I used to labour under the same misapprehension. It doesn't make sense until you join the dots and figure out what a token type actually is.